PowerApps filter excel table and output results
I have a power app that requires a users inputs. When they submut the two inputs (number of stores and state location for stores), I want the submit button to take those inputs, filter them in my excel table and display those results (the filtered data) in a data table in powerapps.
I tried setting up a power automate where i take in the two variables and apply filter arrays to the excel table, but i dont know how to output the results to power apps.
Please help

This question is similar to: PowerApps filter Excel data table. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.
